# Can't decrypt encrypted files with encryptr R-package

Tags: r, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt a dataframe in R with RSA using the `encryptr` package. It works fine until I try to decrypt it again which doesn't work for some reason. Yes, I've triple checked whether the password is correct, I've entered it with and without copy/paste and I have tried different passwords and datasets. I suspect I'm doing something wrong in general and I'm happy about any pointers. Here's a reproducible example that works fine for encrypting but doesn't let me decrypt the data again:

```
# loading test data
data <- mtcars

# generating keys with password
password = "THISISATEST"
genkeys()

# encrypting data
data_encrypt = data %>% 
  encrypt(colnames(data))

# checking encrypted data
View(data_encrypt)

#decrypting data
data_decrypt <- data_encrypt %>%  
                decrypt(colnames(data_encrypt))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It asking for the password again isn't it rejecting the password.

You need to enter your password for every column. So you need to enter your password 10 times in a row when you `decrypt`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Is it different if I encrypt the file as a whole? Would be nice if I only had to enter the PW once.

Comment: If you [encrypt a whole CSV](https://encrypt-r.org/#encrypt-file), you should only have to enter your password once.